# how to solve nodemon is not found in npm | occurred when run server

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, compiler-errors, nodemon

I have a problem: nodemon does not run off the npm script (e.g. npm start),
but if nodemon is called on the command line outside the npm script, nodemon runs as normal.

```
$ nodemon server.js
11 Feb 22:59:51 - [nodemon] v1.3.7
11 Feb 22:59:51 - [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
11 Feb 22:59:51 - [nodemon] watching: *.*
11 Feb 22:59:51 - [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
```

How it is called in npm script:

```
package.json

{
...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  }
}
```

When npm start script is run:

```
$ npm start
> aaa@0.0.1 start /home/akul/Documents/aaa
> nodemon server.js

sh: 1: nodemon: not found

npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-45-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/home/akul/npm-global/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! aaa@0.0.1 start: `nodemon server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 127
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the aaa@0.0.1 start script 'nodemon server.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the aaa package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     nodemon server.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls aaa
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/akul/Documents/aaa/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `which nodemon`, `which npm` and `which node`. My best guess is you have multiple versions of node, but even that doesn't really explain the missing nodemon.

Comment: also the way to ensure nodemon works in your app, no matter the outside state, is to install nodemon as a dev dependency to the project. Even then you should probably fix whatever this is.

Comment: nodemon version is already added.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this problem by instaling nodemon globally in your system.

```
npm install -g nodemon --save-dev
```

The problem happens when nodemon does not exist in /node_modules/.bin.

Added --save-dev since it's required during development only.

Comment: It looks like you already had a global version. `npm install nodemon --save-dev` will install it locally. No need for the `-g`. Even then, npm should still reference the global `PATH` if you have `nodemon` somewhere.